SAS code runs fine, but I get this one error saying "ERROR: Import unsuccessful. See SAS Log for details."
I got the code running fine cause it does prints out results etc, but I'm wondering whether its fine or not, getting that error. Trying to fix it but no luck there.
So this is the LOG file i'm getting everytime I run and like I said the code runs and prints out results which by the way it looks they look just about right. But I don't want to have that ERROR coming up on my code. Should I just ignore it since it runs fine? Or anyone got any ideas?
LOG File

The lines above what you have taken the photograph of should show the data step that PROC IMPORT generated and any errors that resulted.  How are you running SAS?  If you are using SAS Display Manager you can issue the RECALL command to have the generated data step called back into the program editor.

9 times out of 10 this means it did import the data, but it found some unexpected values. For example, characters where there should be numbers. This can happen because of data errors or shifted rows. For example, consider the table below:
char,num
a,1
b,2
c,z

Let's try importing it with PROC IMPORT and force the guessing rows to be 2. This means it's going to look at the header and first row of data, and, based on what's in it, make a guess as to what variable type it should be. In this case, it's going to see a and 1, then assume char and num are characters and numbers, respectively.
proc import 
    file = ".../mycsv.txt"
    out  = test
    dbms = csv
    replace;
    guessingrows=2;
run;

But, we get an error in the log.
NOTE: Invalid data for num in line 4 3-3.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                      
4         c,z 3
char=c num=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=3

Errors detected in submitted DATA step. Examine log.
3 rows created in WORK.TEST from .../mycsv.txt.
  
ERROR: Import unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.34 seconds
      cpu time            0.09 seconds

The dataset was created and I can look at it, but notice that num has a missing value on row 3 because it tried to read in a character as a number.
By default, PROC IMPORT guesses the first 20 rows and makes a conclusion as to what variable type it is. You can increase this up to 2,147,483,647 rows (or, use the keyword MAX). In your case, you may need to increase the number of guessing rows. This increases the amount of time it takes PROC IMPORT to run, but increase it further to see if it can identify the incorrect assumption that it's making for a variable and correct for it.

Note that program will run fine if you have included Z in the list of valid one letter codes for importing special missing values in your MISSING statement. The value of NUM on the last observation would then be .Z instead of . and there would not be any invalid data messages.

Appreciate the insight, thank you!! It did help
